# Spring security login not working, no JSESSIONID cookie returned and redirect fails

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-security, axios

I'm trying to write an application with separated Backend (written using Spring Boot, and Spring Security for login) and Frontend (ReactJS). Right now I'm struggling with accessing a secured endpoint after a successful login.

**What I want to achieve:** Make a GET to secured endpoint e.g. '/books/all'. If user not logged in, return 401. If 401 received on front-end, make a POST to '/login'. Then I want to have a successful login and to be able to make a successful GET to '/books/all'.

**What doesn't work:** The last part. I'm making a POST to '/login' and receive 200 GET. Then I make a second call to '/books/all' and receive GET 401. Also I no longer receive JSESSIONID cookie which worries me.

**My question:** how to fix this behavior? I believe it's connected to JSESSIONID (server doesn't send information about user being successfully logged in?).

On front-end I'm using axios.

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/book/anna/all')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response rebuild');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 401 && response.request.responseURL === 'http://localhost:8080/login') {
                axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', 'username=c&password=d')
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('response 2');
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error 2');
            console.log(error);
            axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', 'username=c&password=d')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('response 2');
                    console.log(response);
                    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/book/anna/all')
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log('response 3');
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log('error 3');
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(error);
                })
        });
```

Please mind that I'm aware that this code it's low quality; it's just temporary to check if redirection after login is working.

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.shareabook.security;

import com.shareabook.repository.UsersRepository;
import com.shareabook.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/anna/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler);
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().permitAll();

        http
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/rest/author/all");
    }

    private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler.java

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

RESTAuthenticationSuccessfulHandler.java

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

//        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", "c");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

BooksController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/book")
public class BookController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8888")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/anna/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> securedHello() {
        List<String> word = new ArrayList<>();
        word.add("all");
        System.out.print(word);
        return word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have enabled forms authentication on your application. At the moment you send the post to login page Spring authenticates your request and by default caches the authnetication on user session.

Later you can send requests to server bound to the same session without additional authentication information. But you need to provide session information on your request. Usually this is done by supplying the `JSESSIONID` cookie on your next requests. Browser does this for you automatically *but only after page reload*. If you stay of the same page only cookies loaded for that page initially will be sent back to server.

For SPA applications I would suggest using token-based authentication instead of forms. You will have first to login and receive a token in response. Next you will have to supply `Authorization` header with each your request providing token as authentication information (usually in form `Bearer <token>`)

Comment: Hi @AlehMeksimovich! Thank you for your answer. I want to make it token-based authentication in the future. Correct me if I'm wrong but the steps I have so far shouldn't change with token, should they? I will still have to make a POST to '/login' and then generate a token on backend. I tried to make some changes along the line which you suggested - the second call to GET '/books/all' is done separately and after I manually refreshed the page. Unfortunately I still have 401 error and no JSESSIONID cookie is present. Any more suggestions? I'd most grateful.

Comment: I can assume that you have a static website that resides on a separate location/container. When you first send request to server to login a new session is created. In reply you get a new cookie with jsessionid. But since this is an AJAX request its cookies will not be picked up by browser automatically. It will work either if you pass the jsessionid manually on next request or if you first hit separate login page and browser will accept the response and redirect you to website on the same domain. In all other cases next AJAX request will start a new session on server.

Comment: This article should help you understand what is going on https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich can you please give more details as how spring security validates these jsession cookies out of the box? I have not configured any db so I am guessing session information must be getting stored in memory. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but may help someone.

Try to add header `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"` with value `"true"` to your server responses. And in request config of axios calls set option `withCredentials` to `true` as well.